# OpenCv capture with V4L

Tags: opencv, v4l2

I am trying to capture frames from OV13850

but it show very green screen. Almost all green ?

any idea?

Normal gst-camera.sh , gst-launch  showing the camera normally .

But when I try to grab from the below code it all green .

**EDIT :** FULL CODE Here

Ubuntu 18
NanopcT4 board
Ov13850 onboard camera
cpu  not gpu using.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "v4l2_helper.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int width, height;
    static const char* default_videodev = "/dev/video0";
    const char *videodev;
    unsigned int start, end, fps = 0;
    unsigned char* ptr_cam_frame;
    int bytes_used;


    Mat yuyv_frame, preview;


    if (argc == 4) {
        videodev = argv[1];


        string width_str = argv[2];
        string height_str = argv[3];
        try {
            size_t pos;
            width = stoi(width_str, &pos);
            if (pos < width_str.size()) {
                cerr << "Trailing characters after width: " << width_str << '\n';
            }

            height = stoi(height_str, &pos);
            if (pos < height_str.size()) {
                cerr << "Trailing characters after height: " << height_str << '\n';
            }
        } catch (invalid_argument const &ex) {
            cerr << "Invalid width or height\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } catch (out_of_range const &ex) {
            cerr << "Width or Height out of range\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Note: This program accepts (only) three arguments.\n";
        cout << "First arg: device file path, Second arg: width, Third arg: height\n";
        cout << "No arguments given. Assuming default values.\n";
        cout << "Device file path: " << default_videodev << "; Width: 640; Height: 480\n";
        videodev = default_videodev;
        width = 640;
        height = 480;
    }


    if (helper_init_cam(videodev, width, height, V4L2_PIX_FMT_UYVY, IO_METHOD_USERPTR) < 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

#ifdef ENABLE_DISPLAY

    #ifdef ENABLE_GL_DISPLAY
    namedWindow("OpenCV V4L2", CV_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    #else
    namedWindow("OpenCV V4L2");
    #endif
    cout << "Note: Click 'Esc' key to exit the window.\n";
#endif


    yuyv_frame = Mat(height, width, CV_8UC2);

    while(1) {

        if (helper_get_cam_frame(&ptr_cam_frame, &bytes_used) < 0) {
            break;
        }


        yuyv_frame.data = ptr_cam_frame;
        if(yuyv_frame.empty()) {
            cout << "Img load failed" << endl;
            break;
        }


        cvtColor(yuyv_frame, preview, COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY);

#ifdef ENABLE_DISPLAY

    #if (defined ENABLE_GL_DISPLAY) && (defined ENABLE_GPU_UPLOAD)

        gpu_frame.upload(preview);
        imshow("OpenCV V4L2", gpu_frame);
    #else
        imshow("OpenCV V4L2", preview);
    #endif
#endif


        if (helper_release_cam_frame() < 0)
        {
            break;
        }

#ifdef ENABLE_DISPLAY
        if(waitKey(1) == 27) break;
#endif

        fps++;
        end = GetTickCount();
        if ((end - start) >= 1000) {
            cout << "fps = " << fps << endl ;
            fps = 0;
            start = end;
        }


    }


    if (helper_deinit_cam() < 0)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**EDIT-2**

output of the : v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats

ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUYV 4:2:2

```
Index       : 1
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
Name        : YUYV 4:2:2

Index       : 2
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'UYVY'
Name        : UYVY 4:2:2

Index       : 3
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: '422P'
Name        : Planar YVU 4:2:2

Index       : 4
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'NV16'
Name        : Y/CbCr 4:2:2

Index       : 5
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'YU12'
Name        : Planar YUV 4:2:0

Index       : 6
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'YU12'
Name        : Planar YUV 4:2:0

Index       : 7
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'YV12'
Name        : Planar YVU 4:2:0

Index       : 8
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'NV12'
Name        : Y/CbCr 4:2:0

Index       : 9
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'NV21'
Name        : Y/CrCb 4:2:0

Index       : 10
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'GREY'
Name        : 8-bit Greyscale

Index       : 11
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'Y444'
Name        : 16-bit A/XYUV 4-4-4-4

Index       : 12
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'NV24'
Name        : Y/CbCr 4:4:4

Index       : 13
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'JPEG' (compressed)
Name        : JFIF JPEG

Index       : 14
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'RGBP'
Name        : 16-bit RGB 5-6-5

Index       : 15
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'GRBG'
Name        : 8-bit Bayer GRGR/BGBG
```

Comment: How do you think anyone will be able to help when you show incomplete code, give no indication how you compiled it, nor which OS or platform you use, nor the OpenCV version? Please try harder if you want some help. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I edited. stackoveflow complaned the code size this is why I cut before.  thx.

Comment: You appear to be using `cvtColor(... COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY)` to generate your preview frame. I believe you need to convert it to BGR (not `UYVY`) for display. Also, I am not sure why you have a `CV_8UC2` format Mat - I would have expected 3 channels. If you are really stuck, I would put something green in front of the camera and save a single image to a `PPM` format file, then something red and save it to another `PPM` file then something blue and see what's in the PPM files - I suggest `PPM` because they are basically uninterpreted and free of colourspace.

Comment: I will try and let you know. embedded board and embedded camera. lack of support always from manufacturer(china) . I believe there is a simple way to do this .